# Should I use "display: none" class or Javascript based conditional rendering for ISR or SSG Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, static, server-side

One quick question. I use getStaticProps with revalidate (ISR) in a nextjs 12 project. i can see in network tab that when i have 2 image components with same image but different sizes for example, and hide one on big screens and the other on small screens, that the fetch request for the hidden one is marked as "canceled" in the network tab.

Seems fine, 0 bytes fetched and no error response, just canceled. But i want to know if its better to not have it like that by conditionally rendering those images depending on screen size i got via a package, so javascript.

But then the question is is it making the performance worse or better because i use static site generation with revalidation.